# Read a list of models and block new creations

Tags: django

I have an `Order` model that users can create and modify.

An Admin user can get a list of all the orders of the days and send the list.

I would like that before the Admin sends the list, it closes the orders for the current day, so that orders are closed until the next day.

At the moment, I do not really see how to avoid a race condition:
- Admin closes the orders and gets the list
- A user submits an order at the same time and thinks that his order is taken into account.

The solution I have imagined so far is:

- The admin clicks a button which submits a false order which indicates that the orders are closed for the day
- When the form is posted, the list of orders is retrieved
- When posting an order, I will first check if the false order is present. If it is present, validation will fail.

But I think that race conditions are still possible.

Is there a possibility to manage it at the database level ? For example, when closing the commands, add a constraint in the database on the date (Date for new orders must be at least the data of the following day) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the atomic decorator for the database transaction in order to check for a false order. If you add a check within the atomic decorator to check for the race condition it can throw an error and reset the closing day admin order. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this. I will try to implement it but anyway it looks like the correct solution.